# Is there a way to calculate theoretical maximum betweenness a vertex could have by knowing the total numbers of vertices?

Tags: igraph

Can you calculate the potential maximum betweenness for a vertex in a graph?

This is assuming using all defaults for the betweenness() function.

I would think that the maximum betweenness for any vertex would be lower than the number of unique pairs (something approximate to number of unique pairs - total number of vertices).

I know igraph can calculate multiple shortest paths, but from simple models of betweenness, it does not "double count" these.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The highest possible number of shortest paths passing through a vertex in an undirected graph is `(V-1)(V-2)/2` where `V` is the vertex count. This is simply $(V-1) \choose 2$, as we exclude that one vertex when considering pairs.

This value is realized for the center of a star graph.

This is in fact used in igraph's "centralization" functions:

https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Structural.html#igraph_centralization_betweenness_tmax

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is exactly along the lines of what I was thinking. I am asking because I came across a recent publication containing a graph with 35 nodes. The authors said they used the betweenness function in igraph. The node with the highest betweenness value is ~640, and it seemed off to me. Theirs is a directed graph.

Comment: Or maybe since it is a directed graph, you are asking twice as many pairs? For example, in an undirected graph the shortest path from A to B is the same as B to A. But in a directed graph it could be different paths

Comment: Yes, there are 34*33 = 1122 ordered pairs, 640 is possible.